# `unknown encoding name - ISO` error raised when my string contains the chars: "ISO"

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I have an email object (instance of the `mail` gem):

```
header = #<Mail::Message:70363632703900, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2012 13:48:55 +0000>, <From: Mike Tyson <some@email.com>>, <To: <my@email.com>>, <Subject: RE: =?ISO?Q?Ordrebekr=E6ftelse_nummer_CCL1221805621?=>>
```

When I try to access the `subject` (which is a `String` object) by e.g. typing

```
puts header.subject
```

I get this error:

```
unknown encoding name - ISO
```

Instead of just reading the entire string it seems that Ruby reads the `ISO` as the encoding. I have no idea why this is.

**Do anyone have an idea about how to access this string?**

Additional info:

Here is an example of a string that also contains encoding info, but doesn't raise errors:

```
header_2 = #<Mail::Message:70327581075160, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2012 13:01:29 +0100>, <From: J.C.W. <some@email.com>>, <To: Tiger Woods <my@email.com>>, <Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Re=3A_=D8v_alts=E5=2C_vi_er_n=F8dt_til_at_aflyse_din_ordre_?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?107210?=>>
```

Comment: What class is `header.subject`? It might not be a string. Have you tried `puts header.subject.inspect`?

Comment: Hi @Cort3z, Thanks for your comment. I just checked, and the class of the subject is just a plain `String`.

Comment: Try forcing the encoding: `puts header.subject.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the problem is that the error is raised before I can overwrite the encoding. So I never get to envoke the methode you suggest, because an error is raised already on `header.subject`.